# Telegram add and retrieve metadata from message

Tags: aws-lambda, telegram, telegram-bot

Hi I'm looking for a way to store user session/metadata with the least amount of latency and that will not cost me an arm and a leg.

Brief problem description.

I have a bot that helps users download files from Google Drive.

It uses a Webhook of an AWS lambda function.

Users are provided with clickable filenames, e.g.

/File.pdf

Once they click on it, it needs to be downloaded and sent to the user.

The problem is I need a way of knowing what file the user chose without having to use a database or iterating through all my files by name.

**E.g.** Is there a way of adding metadata to the clickable message? Such that I can add that metadata to the clickable and if a user clicks /File.pdf, I'll be able to extract the metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send InlineKeyboardButton like [in this example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#usage-2) and set in `callback_data` whatever you need. When user clicks on that button - your bot will receive that data in update:

```py
button_list = [
    InlineKeyboardButton("File1.pdf", callback_data="https://drive.google.com/invoice.pdf"),
    InlineKeyboardButton("File2.pdf", callback_data="https://drive.google.com/presentation.pdf"),
    InlineKeyboardButton("File3.pdf", callback_data="https://drive.google.com/report.pdf")
]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button_list)
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, "Files list:", reply_markup=reply_markup)


# in update handler:
def some_update_handler(update, context):
    url = update.callback_query.data
    # ...
    # further processing
```

This can be also useful in any other case when Telegram bot user should see some nice message, but shouldn't see some internal value sent to Telegram bot.